# In Qualtrics, how to customize timer length?

Tags: timer, qualtrics

I'm hoping to set up a survey in Qualtrics which will be fixed to last 30 minutes for every participant. This is due to the majority of the survey consisting of audio prompts which are played on a fixed schedule (and using timers to auto-advance to the next audio prompt).

My problem is that there are a few instances in which participants are asked to complete blocks of questions about what they just listened to, and obviously people will differ in the amount of time they take to complete these sections. I was hoping I could somehow track the time (in seconds) a participant spends on these self-report sections, then have a timer page at the end of the self-report, customized to delay participants from advancing but based on how long they took to finish the self-report.

For example, let's say after listening to blocks 1,2, and 3 (which are all timed audio), I want all participants to spend a total of 3 minutes on blocks 4,5, and 6 (which consist of self-report questions) before moving to block 7. If John finishes blocks 4,5, and 6, in 2.5 minutes, I'd then like John to wait for 30 seconds before continuing to 7. If Sally finishes blocks 4,5, and 6 in 2 minutes, I'd like her to wait 60 seconds before continuing.

Hope that makes sense, and greatly appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1):

The variable ${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration} always contains the current number of seconds since the beginning of the survey.

You can add a javascript to the last question in Block 6 where you pipe in Q_TotalDuration and hide the Next button until you hit the time limit, then show the Next button.